# Error en foreach

Tags: c#

como recientemente empecé a programar en .NET C# todavía no tengo mucha idea de como funciona...

tengo dentro de una base de datos una tabla con 7 registros. Pero cuando hago un SELECT de esa tabla desde mi clase, solo me toma los valores del ultimo registro...

Este es el codigo del metodo para recuperar los datos de la tabla:

```
    public static List<Facturas> BuscarFacturas(int NroVendedor)
    {
        int NroVendedor = 5;

        List<Facturas> Listafacturas = new List<Facturas>();
        Facturas factura = new Facturas();

        string ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            string queryDB = "SELECT * FROM Facturas WHERE NroVendedor=@NroVendedor";
            parameters.Add("@NroVendedor", NroVendedor);

            DataTable dtDB = DefineBD.dba_DataTable_ParamHash(queryDB, parameters);

            foreach (DataRow fac in dtDB.Rows)
            {
                factura.NroFactura = fac.Field<int>("NroFactura");
                factura.Concepto = fac.Field<String>("Concepto");
                factura.Importe = fac.Field<decimal>("Importe");
                factura.Fecha = fac.Field<DateTime>("Fecha");
                factura.NroCliente = fac.Field<int>("NroCliente");
                factura.NroVendedor = fac.Field<int>("NroVendedor");

                Listafacturas.Add(factura);
            }
        }

        return Listafacturas;
    }
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que este método me devuelva una lista de la tabla Facturas pero lo que me devuelve es una lista con el ultimo registro...

Esto es lo que devuelve:

> 7
>   Producto 7
>   5
>   2017-03-30T00:00:00
>   3
>   5
>
> 7
>   Producto 7
>   5
>   2017-03-30T00:00:00
>   3
>   5
>
> 7
>   Producto 7
>   5
>   2017-03-30T00:00:00
>   3
>   5
>
> 7
>   Producto 7
>   5
>   2017-03-30T00:00:00
>   3
>   5
>
> 7
>   Producto 7
>   5
>   2017-03-30T00:00:00
>   3
>   5
>
> 7
>   Producto 7
>   5
>   2017-03-30T00:00:00
>   3
>   5
>
> 7
>   Producto 7
>   5
>   2017-03-30T00:00:00
>   3
>   5

Y esto es lo que me debería devolver:

> 1
>   Producto 1
>   25
>   2017-03-30T00:00:00
>   1
>   5
>
> 2
>   Producto 2
>   32
>   2017-03-30T00:00:00
>   1
>   5
>
> 3
>   Producto 3
>   15
>   2017-03-30T00:00:00
>   2
>   5
>
> 4
>   Producto 4
>   500
>   2017-03-30T00:00:00
>   2
>   5
>
> 5
>   Producto 5
>   200
>   2017-03-30T00:00:00
>   2
>   5
>
> 6
>   Producto 6
>   10
>   2017-03-30T00:00:00
>   3
>   5
>
> 7
>   Producto 7
>   5
>   2017-03-30T00:00:00
>   3
>   5

No puedo encontrar donde está el error, alguien podría ayudarme?

Muchas Gracias de Antemano!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

El problema es que dentro del ciclo, estás siempre sobre-escribiendo la misma instancia de `Facturas` y agregando esa misma instancia a la lista varias veces. Por lo que al final, tu lista simplemente contiene varias referencias a la misma instancia de `Facturas` con los datos que sobre-escribistes la última vez.

Para corregir tu error, debes crear una nueva instancia de `Facturas` al comenzar cada ciclo.

De modo que remueve esta sentencia:

```
Facturas factura = new Facturas();
```

... y muévela dentro del ciclo de esta manera:

```
foreach (DataRow fac in dtDB.Rows)
{
    Facturas factura = new Facturas(); // <-- mueve esta sentencia dentro del ciclo.

    factura.NroFactura = fac.Field<int>("NroFactura");
    factura.Concepto = fac.Field<String>("Concepto");
    factura.Importe = fac.Field<decimal>("Importe");
    factura.Fecha = fac.Field<DateTime>("Fecha");
    factura.NroCliente = fac.Field<int>("NroCliente");
    factura.NroVendedor = fac.Field<int>("NroVendedor");

    Listafacturas.Add(factura);
}
```

Comment: funciono perfectamente... muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 7):

Una solución que puedes probar (y que personalmente considero más elegante) es modificar tu ciclo (y ni siquiera declarar tu objeto `factura`) con el siguiente ciclo:

```
foreach (DataRow fac in dtDB.Rows)
{
    Listafacturas.Add(new Facturas()
    {
        NroFactura = fac.Field<int>("NroFactura"),
        Concepto = fac.Field<String>("Concepto"),
        Importe = fac.Field<decimal>("Importe"),
        Fecha = fac.Field<DateTime>("Fecha"),
        NroCliente = fac.Field<int>("NroCliente"),
        NroVendedor = fac.Field<int>("NroVendedor")
    });
}
```